# php + api: download and eval code on client site -> is it good idea?

Tags: php, api

We provide link aggregator service.

Terms:
1) client api: client api code, written in php, that we provide for our clients
2) client: client site, that uses client api to get ( from our server ) and display html links

Api is very simple.
All, what client is care about, is just to get and diplay links. Nothing more.
Currently, it looks something like this:

```
<?php
require_once('/path/to/lib.php'); // all logic is here ( what to send, log, ...)
$obj = new Obj();
echo $obj->getData(); // html links
?>
```

The problem is, that after upgrade of client api, we have to give it to each client to upload on their sites.
So, this is very inconvenient.

**What do you think about following idea**:
Place lib.php to server and upgrade client api so it downloads and eval that code.
So, we can control everything happening on client sites in one place.

What do you think ?
What should i take in mind ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **What do you think about following idea:**
>   Place lib.php to server and
>   upgrade client api so it downloads and eval that code. So, we can
>   control everything happening on client sites in one place.

Any segment of code that is allowed to automatically update is a *significant* security concern.

Depending on how affluent your customer base is, it may be an acceptable risk.  But more likely than not, they would not understand or be aware of the implications.  This brings up another point which is often overlooked.

> What should i take in mind?

What liability do you assume if something goes wrong, or a vulnerability is caused (or even suspected) by your code?

Anyone choosing to work with you would have to implicitly have faith in all of your systems.

Sorry, not on my watch.

Comment: Yes, as it is expected, security is a problem. I am interested, what is the best way to make this approach the safest. What client should do with permissions, ..